# mysql join on condition behavior

Tags: mysql

I am failing to understand the behavior of conditional join. Here is a comment table where there are two types of users. if the user_type_id=1 then the data should come from admins table, if the user_type_id=2 then the data should come from users table.

[image]

So I wrote the query as follows:

```
 select a.name as admin_name, concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as user_name, ptc.*
    from project_task_comments ptc 
    left join admins a on a.id= ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=1
    left join users u on u.id=ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=2
    and ptc.id=1
```

And Here is the result:

[image]

my question is why (in the result set) the row 3 and 5 has admin_name and user_name is null? Am I missing something?

admins table:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | ADMIN John Doe |
+----+----------------+
```

users table:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | User       | Alice     |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: are you certain that users 3 and 5 exist in either the users or the admins table? To avoid problems, I'd recommend multiple-clause joins to be enclosed in parentheses, such as `left join admins a on (a.id= ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=1)`

Comment: for both type of user, the user_id is same which is 1

Comment: Post CREATE + INSERT statements with data which will reproduce the behavior. Without knowing the data, we can tell you nothing.

Comment: *"my question is why (in the result set) the row 3 and 5 has admin_name and user_name is null? Am I missing something?"* It can be the case that those `project_task_comments`  does not have a admin and or a user.. but without example data and expected results we can't help you see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Both table has only one user. which is given on the question

Comment: it what more meant for helping you provide all example data and expected results as formatted text, images are bad to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your data, there're three records for "ptc.user_type_id=2", 1. ptc.id = 1 2. ptc.id = 3 3. ptc.id = 5 In your query you've already mentioned to put records which belongs to the first instance (i.e. ptc.id = 1). 
So if you wants all three then you need to use the following query.

```html
SELECT a.name as admin_name, concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as user_name, ptc.* 
FROM project_task_comments ptc 
  left join admins a on a.id= ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=1 
  left join users u on u.id=ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=2
```

Comment: Removed my downvote.. You are probably correct. But you should write what you have changed. And why. We don't want to play a "find the difference" game.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because you gave the answer several mins before and I did not notice!!! Good catch.

Comment: As per your data, there're three records for "ptc.user_type_id=2",
1. ptc.id = 1
2. ptc.id = 3
3. ptc.id = 5

In your query you've already mentioned to put records which  belongs to the first instance (i.e. ptc.id = 1). So if you wants all three then you need to use the following query.

 select a.name as admin_name, concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as user_name, ptc.*
    from project_task_comments ptc 
    left join admins a on a.id= ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=1
    left join users u on u.id=ptc.user_id and ptc.user_type_id=2

Comment: That should be in the answer - Not in comment. Just [edit] your answer and copy&paste your comment.

Comment: @KamranFeroz Edit your answer with the above comment, so any downvoter will remove their downvotes.

Comment: That WHERE clause fixed all the problems.. So the last line I wrote as-> WHERE ptc.project_task_id=1 which solved all the problems

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you need to SELECT the main table (e.g. users) and do TWO conditional joins of the related tables.

This will generally mean that internally, your query will return an array of rows in the following manner:
comment.* | user.* | admin.*

For some rows, you will have null columns for the user columns, for other rows you will have null columns for the admin columns. In the end, you will probably need the first non-null value.

So if you have a row such as:

```
comment.id | comment.text | user.username | admin.username
123 | "Example text" | null | john2019
```

In the end you want to escape the `null` and return just the `john2019`.

The MySQL function COALESCE() comes to aid:

```
SELECT comment.id, comment.text, COALESCE(user.username, admin.username)
```

It will select the first, non-null column from the provided ones, so the row selected will be:

```
123 | "Example text" | john2019
```

I hope you find this not too confusing. Let me know in a comment below if you need further clarification.